# Split string in R by \ character

Tags: r, split, strsplit

I have column `sr$classf` in `sr` dataframe with string like hierarchy `servicegroup\service\servicerequest\`. I want to split string with `strsplit()` by `\` character and put different parts of splitted string in additional columns.
For example I create `sr.c7$service` column ans put first part before `\`

```
 sr$service <- as.character(lapply(strsplit(as.character(sr$classf), split="\"), "[", 1))
```

But R comment out all code following `split="\"`. What should I do to use `\` as a split parameter?

**Solution:**

```
 sr$service <- as.character(lapply(strsplit(as.character(sr$classf), split="\\\\"), "[", 1))
```

Comment: `strsplit("\\\\", x)`

Comment: Avinash, thank you! Can you explain the logic? Maybe you can provide link on docs?

Comment: In my case solution code looks like following  sr$service <- as.character(lapply(strsplit(as.character(sr$classf), split="\\\\"), "[", 1))

Comment: What's your input and what would be your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Use four backslashes to match a single backslash character.

```
strsplit("foo\\bar", "\\\\")[[1]]
#[1] "foo" "bar"
```